# How to create multiple responses for a POST statement in swagger UI?

Tags: post, swagger-ui, openapi

***Warning**: The way the API I am configuring goes against best practice. Unfortunately its something I am forced to do based off requirements. Therefore I apologize if this question seems odd. I am not looking for "well, you should have built your API this way" statements, its not up to me, just asking what is possible.*

Right now we have one URI route to take all POST requests. The structure of the json payload determines what actions will be performed by the API.

This means I need one POST method, and a way to show different examples and responses for each.

I figured out how to use components > schemas  to create multiple schema bodies, then apply those to different examples. This will give me a dropdown in SwaggerUI to choose different examples.

However, I need the response's to adjust when each example is chosen. This is because we return different responses depending on how the JSON structure is sent. Example, there are 5 different 200OK responses, and each sends a different payload structure.

Is it possible to have the response section adjust depending on which item is selected form the example dropdown? or is there a way to create a response dropdown for a user to see choose manually?